# Buscar registro anterior y siguiente del seleccionado en laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

como puedo obtener el registro anterior y el que sigue de el registro seleccionado.

ejemplo: tengo el registro 2 pero quiero que me busque el 1 y el 3. como puedo buscarlo en eloquent?

Comment: agrega más detalles a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en el modelo puedes crear un par de funciones para traerlos:

```
public function siguiente(){
    return Modelo::where('id', '>', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
}

public function previo(){
    return Modelo::where('id', '<', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
}
```

Comment: Si esas funciones ya las tengo que es previous y next que son las mismas funciones que tu tienes pero con el firs me trae el primer registro de la tabla y el ultimo registro de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada me imagino que tienes el id del registro, lo que puedes hacer muy sencillamente es agregar una sentencia de tipo "whereIn"
Un ejemplo basico sería que tengas el id numero 2, con una resta y una suma sabes cuales necesitas, la sentencia pide que los valores esten almacenados en un array [] podrías pasarlo de la siguiente manera o en una variable.

```
->whereIn('id', [1,3])
->get();
```

Con esto obtendras lo que necesitas, saludos.

---

En efecto mi estimado ahora si entiendo tu pregunta, lo que podrías hacer es obtener los resultados que buscas de la siguiente forma,

```
select id from tabla where tabla.id < (id que tienes) order by id desc limit 1
select id from tabla where tabla.id > (id que tienes) order by id asc limit 1
```

de esta forma obtienes los valores que necesitas, así quedaría la consulta lo unico que tendrías que hacer es reescribirla con laravel.

Comment: Si ese seria el caso si los Id fueran secuenciales. pero si los id estan en posiciones diferentes no me traeria el resultado.

Comment: Ejemplo: id = 1,2,4,7,9,10  y quiero obtener los que están al rededor del 7 es decir el 4 y el 9 esa función que mencionas no me serviria

Comment: respondi a tu pregunta, edite la publicación.

Comment: si. con la función en laravel de Jonathan pude lograr el objetivo

Comment: Excelente lo vi un poco tarde.